# When generating script using update-database -script it also creates create script for _MigrationHistory?

Tags: orm, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, database-migration

My application has around 300 migrations out of that around 260 are already in the production, now we have to release a new version of the software with those newly added migrations.

Generally, we generate a DB script for deployment and then run that script on the production DB, this time around when I was trying to generate the script using *update-database -script* command it's adding a script to create the _MigrationHistory table despite that table already exists in the database?

Please see full issue detail here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/745

Is there any fix for this problem?

Comment: facing same issue.